# remote roslaunch failed to launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro, husky, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to launch nodes on a remote master machine through a launch file. My ssh keys are setup for passwordless connection. The husky.machine file to configure the launch ssh connections to the remote computer is:

```
<launch>
<arg name="robot_0_ip" default="$(env ROS_MASTER_IP)" />

<machine name="robot_0"
         address="$(arg robot_0_ip)"
         user="ros"
         env-loader="/home/ros/catkin_ws/husky_launcher.sh"
         ssh-port="22"
         timeout="20" />
</launch>
```

I stripped down my main launch file, system.launch to this:

```
<launch>
    #### 1: ARBITER - ROBOT COMPUTER CONFIGURATIONS ###########
    <include file="$(find husky_pursuit)/launch/game/husky.machine" />

    #### 2: ARBITER - ARENA SETUP ###########
    <include file="$(find husky_pursuit)/launch/game/arbiter.launch" /> # local

    #### 3/4: ROBOT - ROBOT LAUNCHES ###########
    <node machine="robot_0" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.25 0 0.25 0 0 0 /robot_0/base_link /robot_0/laser 40" />
</launch>
```

It just launches one node remotely on robot_0 (the master), a static_transform_publisher. Before running this launch file, I ssh into robot_0 and run roscore. The error from running system.launch is:

```
... logging to /home/ajay/.ros/log/81f340de-1106-11e4-a670-801f02abdf53/roslaunch-i72ubuntu-12392.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http:// 192.168.1.119:35719/
remote[192.168.1.125-0] starting roslaunch
remote[192.168.1.125-0]: creating ssh connection to 192.168.1.125:22, user[ros]
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http:// 192.168.1.125:11311 /home/ros/catkin_ws/husky_launcher.sh roslaunch -c 192.168.1.125-0 -u http:// 192.168.1.119:35719/ --run_id 81f340de-1106-11e4-a670-801f02abdf53]
remote[192.168.1.125-0]: ssh connection created
[192.168.1.125-0] killing on exit
remote roslaunch failed to launch: robot_0
```

Based on the log file, SSH authentication was successful, but ProcessMonitor shuts down. The log file is at pastebin.com/Q2t3hEpp

Why does the remote roslaunch fail to launch?

Thanks!

EDIT: /home/ros/catkin_ws/husky_launcher.sh env-loader file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ROS_WS=/home/ros/catkin_ws
source $ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$ROS_WS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http:// 192.168.1.125:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.125
```

(I added a space between http:// and 192.168.125:11311 because I can't publish links yet. It's not really there on the robot computer).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187320/remote-roslaunch-failed-to-launch/) by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-21**:
I've usually seen issues like this when there was an error in the environment loader script. Can you edit your question to include your environment loader?

**Comment by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on 2014-07-21**:
I added the script. It sources the workspace devel/setup.bash file - does it also need to source /opt/ros/hydro/env.sh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your environment loader looks reasonable, except that the last line should be `exec "$@"`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on 2014-07-22**:
Thanks - this worked! Now I just need to resolve my TF extrapolation into the past errors...